# SIMPLE CODE: How to define a ranging variable? (Code error)

Tags: python, function, if-statement, variables, traceback

The code outputs an error: name 'numAttacks' is not defined. How do I define numAttacks if it will be based on user's input in def difficulty?

```
def fightBattle(difficulty):
    if (difficulty == "easy"):
        numAttacks = 10
    elif (difficulty == "hard"):
        numAttacks = 5
difficulty = input("Which difficulty mode you wish to play on?: (Easy/ Hard) ")


def game():
    for i in range (numAttacks):
        print("Village")
game()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function should return the value so you can assign it to the variable.

```
def fightBattle(difficulty):
    if (difficulty == "easy"):
        numAttacks = 10
    elif (difficulty == "hard"):
        numAttacks = 5
    else:
        raise ValueError("Difficulty should be easy or hard")
    return numAttacks

def game():
    print("something")
    difficulty = input("Which difficulty mode you wish to play on?: (Easy/ Hard) ")
    numAttacks = fightBattle(difficulty)
    for i in range (numAttacks):
        print("Village")

game()
```